# Motherboard is showing 24v instead of 12v

Tags: motherboard, bios, power-supply, voltage

I have put together a new PC build and when I turn on the machine it's showing me the following error/warning:
"*Asus anti-surge was triggered to protect system from unstable power supply*"

Besides that, everything functions as normal.(though I couldn't get windows to boot from the SSD after installation, but I'm assuming that's a different issue)

In the bios the 5V and 12V are both highlighted in red. The 5V is showing as 6.440V, and the 12V is showing as 24.480V.

I have the 20+4 plugged into the main motherboard socket, and one of the CPU4+4 plugged into the other 4-pin socket.(it comes with 2x separate cables labelled "Left" and "Right")

I haven't been able to procure a DMM yet so I'm not able to definitively confirm if it's the PSU. But from looking online I get the impression it's more likely to be the motherboard.

I've tried resetting the CMOS settings in bios and removing the motherboard battery.

My equipment is:
- **Motherboard - B150M-A:** https://www.asus.com/au/Motherboards/B150M-A/overview/
- **PSU - RX-535AP:** http://www.raidmax.com/power-supplies_rx-535ap.html

Comment: *"it's more likely to be the motherboard."* -- No it's not.  Since the largest voltage from the PSU is +12VDC, the MB *"malfunction"* would have to double that voltage.  That's not likely.  The simpler explanation is a malfunctioning PSU.

Comment: @sawdust thanks for the input. do you know of any way I can confirm where the fault lies without a voltmeter?

Comment: I actually seriously doubt that a power supply would output 24V instead of 12V.  It sounds like there is some really bad connection somewhere causing this.

Comment: Did you try disconnecting everything that is not needed to go in the BIOS setup?

Comment: A voltmeter (or multimeter) is an essential tool.  Substitution of a known-to-be good PSU is the alternative.  BTW what is the AC line voltage where you are?

Comment: @JuliePelletier I've disconnected everything but RAM, CPU, CPU Fan, Power Button and monitor. The voltages are showing the same in bios.

Comment: @sawdust I completely agree. I'm hoping to get a voltmeter tomorrow and unfortunately I have no working PSU to swap out.

Comment: @sawdust's question on AC voltage makes a lot of sense and I wonder if that may be the issue.

Comment: @sawdust it's meant to be 230V in Australia. Though I suppose that's something else I can't be certain of.

Comment: Any chance you somehow managed to cram some connector the wrong way in? If the board expects +12V and 0V, but gets +12V and -12V, that would explain the 24V measurement.

Comment: @Mario I thought(and hoped) the same thing. But I've checked and re-checked and they are all clipped in the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At 24V, the MB and other components would of been almost certainly damaged. Probably the sensors in the MB are malfunctioning /calibrated wrong.

Your best bet is to get a voltmeter and measure any red+black (the 5V) and any yellow+black (12V) wires from HDD connector or 24-pin main MB connector. Usually the 5V is a very exact value, while the 12V can be a little higher, but in no case as high as 24V.

Comment: Thank you @Overmind. I was thinking the same thing, I've had components fried for less. Though I would be easier to ascertain if it is the PSU.  
  
Thank you for the instructions on how to measure the 12/5V voltage it's made it a lot easier. I'll be able to jump in and check that out today. I'm going to mark yours as the correct answer as I think it's the best one can offer with the information I have so far.

Comment: Don't forget to post the measurements/finding.

Comment: I was able to get a multi-meter and measured the PSU following your instructions. They both read correctly at 12v and 5v, so I think the motherboard is faulty and giving false readings, would you agree with that? I don't know anything about electricals but my assumption is that it's impossible for the motherboard to somehow amplify the voltage to 24v? And therefore is a false reading?

Comment: Well, then its clear: the BIOS readings are totally wrong - that may be caused by the sensors themselves or the calibration. Try to make a BIOS update, maybe you will get correct readings after that. If it's a calibration problem, a BIOS update may fix it.

Comment: I've updated the bios and unfortunately no change. I've now organised a replacement and that should take care of it. Thanks for your advice @Overmind I appreciate it, I'm glad it was a incorrect reading and I haven't fried my hardware. :)

Comment: Glad it's nothing serious.